# tailwind font-weight doesn't work in chrome

Tags: css, tailwind-css

this is my globals.css code

```
.inputButton {
    @apply flex items-center space-x-2 font-medium cursor-pointer text-sm;
  }
```

```
 <div className="flex items-center flex-wrap gap-y-4 justify-center md:gap-x-10">
        <button className="inputButton group">
          <PhotoSizeSelectActualIcon className="text-blue-400" />
          <h4 className="opacity-80 group-hover:opacity-100">Photo</h4>
        </button>
        <button className="inputButton group">
          <VideoCameraBackIcon className="text-green-400" />
          <h4 className="opacity-80 group-hover:opacity-100">Video</h4>
        </button>
        <button className="inputButton group">
          <BusinessCenterIcon className="text-blue-300" />
          <h4 className="opacity-80 group-hover:opacity-100">Job</h4>
        </button>
        <button className="inputButton group">
          <ArticleIcon className="text-red-400" />
          <h4 className="opacity-80 group-hover:opacity-100 whitespace-nowrap">
            Write Article
          </h4>
        </button>
      </div>
```

[image]

if i remove font-weight: inherit, it accept font-bold

but i press f5, it's return..

Comment: try to remove the  `h4`, and increase the font-size

Comment: these don't use together? heading and font-weight